# Sharepoint designer 2010 - Workflow Visualization

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, visio-services

I'm using SharePoint designer 2010.
I have created workflow on custom list.

When I operate the workflow I want to see it visually. How can I do it?

P.S.
I am using the "Export To Visio" option. Is it possible to combine between the Sharepoint 2010 and Visio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have [SharePoint Enterprise Edition](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/Pages/Editions-Comparison.aspx) with [Visio Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663485.aspx).

Then it is simple. You just need to enable `Show workflow visualization on status page` under `Workflow settings` (SharePoint Designer).

More info can be found in this article by Wictor Wilén:

[SharePoint 2010 and Visio 2010: Better together - Part 3](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/SharePoint-2010-and-Visio-2010-Better-together-Part-3.aspx)